# Page Transition not working (jQuery mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to learn jQuery mobile. I tried to use `data-transition` used for page transition, but it's showing the default `fade` transition only for other transistion, even if i using other transitions like `pop`, `flip` etc

I'm able to view all transitions displayed on [jQuery docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)

Here's my html body :

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-title="Page 1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Hi! I'm the content in the page</p>
        <!-- Have used `data-transistion` below -->
        <a href="#page2" data-transistion="flip">Page 2</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#popup" data-rel="dialog">Pop Up</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer 1</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="b" data-title="Page 2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Hi! I'm the content in the page 2</p>
        <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
        <a data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer 2</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="popup" data-theme="b" data-title="Pop Up">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Pop Up</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Hi! I'm the content in the Pop Up</p>
        <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Pop Up</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: which versions are you using, jQuery and jQuery Mobile?

Comment: you must be on a browser that supports 3D transforms.